# IE7 Corners inside a TH

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've added corners to a th on both sides, but on IE7 they wont show up.

Even worst , when I use the "Insepctor" of ie (F12), and removes any propety from the page (simply renders the page again), they suddenly show up!!

WTF??

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="process_table_top" colspan="2">
             <div class="corner-2 trp"></div>
             <div class="corner-2 tlp"></div>
        <strong>Personal Details</strong>
        </th>
      </tr>
</thead>
```

CSS:

```
.corner-2.tlp{ background:url(/images/buy_process/table-sprite.png);background-position: 0 -18px; width: 5px; height: 4px; top:5px;left:5px;position:absolute;}
.corner-2.trp{ background:url(/images/buy_process/table-sprite.png);background-position: 0 -27px; width: 5px; height: 5px; top:5px;right:5px;position:absolute;}
```

Comment: Your background-position values seem odd for top left and right corners.  You'd also want the table/container to have position: relative; applied.

Comment: I did, the code is ugly because it tried many ways to deal with the problem, all came back to the same point - IE7 refuses to render the background images.

Comment: can you create a live example at http://www.jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net/ with your sprite to understand better what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `position:absolute;` you need to also specify the parent element to have `position:relative;` - in your case, this would be the `<th>` element.

If you don't specify `position:relative;` for the parent element, the `position:absolute;` element will take it's positioning from the next element up the DOM tree that has `position:relative;`, all the way up to the `<body>` element.

Therefore the solution is to put `position:relative;` on your `<th>` element(s).

You haven't specified whether the "corners" you're making are of the "rounded corner" variety? If that's what you're trying to do, why not throw away the whole thing of using corner graphics for the rounded corners. There are much better ways to do this.

The standard way of doing rounded corners now is to use the CSS3 style `border-radius`. This works as standard in all browsers except IE. You possibly know this, but you obviously need it to work in IE. The good news is that there are a number of hacks available which make the `border-radius` style work for IE as well.

My favourite is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/). Very easy to use, and you don't have to worry about any extra markup or graphics in your HTML code.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

IE 7 has some quote agressive caching which sometimes leads to unexpected behaviour when developing and testing. You probably should use Ctrl+F5 to force a reload without using the cache, or clear the cache before a reload.

Comment: I did, I deleted all cache related files, history, cookies, anything you can think of, even restarted my computer and removed caching.
Also - I checked it on IE7 on a separate virtual machine, still - nothing.